# xsl to get deeply nested elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Based on this xml:

```
<group name="G0">
    <group name="G1" />
    <group name="G2" />
    <group name="G3">
        <group name="G3_1" />
        <group name="G3_2" />
        <group name="G3_3">
            <test name="T1" />
            <test name="T2" />
            <test name="T3" />
        </group>
    </group>
    <group name="G4">
        <test name="T4" />
        <test name="T5" />
    </group>
    <group name="G5">
        <group name="G5_1">
            <group name="G5_1_1" />
            <group name="G5_1_2">
                <group name="G5_1_2_1">
                    <test name="T6" />
                    <test name="T7" />
                    <test name="T8" />
                    <test name="T9" />
                </group>
            </group>
        </group>
    </group>
</group>
```

Is there any way to remove those elements that do not contain test element on its children? to create a result like this. The idea is to insert only the elements that contain tests into the database but including the information about its parents to figure out where do the tests came from. Thankss

```
<group name="G0">
    <group name="G3">
        <group name="G3_3">
            <test name="T1" />
            <test name="T2" />
            <test name="T3" />
        </group>
    </group>
    <group name="G4">
        <test name="T4" />
        <test name="T5" />
    </group>
    <group name="G5">
        <group name="G5_1">
            <group name="G5_1_2">
                <group name="G5_1_2_1">
                    <test name="T6" />
                    <test name="T7" />
                    <test name="T8" />
                    <test name="T9" />
                </group>
            </group>
        </group>
    </group>
</group>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am looking forward for a solution based on xsl transformation, preferably. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on the comment from @Tomalak, an easier approach would be to do nothing for `<group>` nodes having no children.

```
<xsl:template match="group[not(*)]" />
```

Other option is to use the `descendant` axis to identify the nodes. The following template will check whether any of the `<group>` nodes have `<test>` as it's descendant and only display them in the output.

```
<xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:if test="count(descendant::test) > 0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group[not(*)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<group name="G0">
    <group name="G3">
        <group name="G3_3">
            <test name="T1" />
            <test name="T2" />
            <test name="T3" />
        </group>
    </group>
    <group name="G4">
        <test name="T4" />
        <test name="T5" />
    </group>
    <group name="G5">
        <group name="G5_1">
            <group name="G5_1_2">
                <group name="G5_1_2_1">
                    <test name="T6" />
                    <test name="T7" />
                    <test name="T8" />
                    <test name="T9" />
                </group>
            </group>
        </group>
    </group>
</group>
```

Comment: Easier: `<xsl:template match="group[not(*)]" />`

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the optimized approach. I have edited the solution based on your comment.